# How to add flash message to custom installation profile?

Tags: 7, installation, distributions

I have a custom installation profile and I want to display flash message by using [drupal_set_message](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) on home page after install.

How can I do it?

Comment: check this http://drupal.org/project/better_messages  or  http://drupal.org/project/popup_message